# '=' not recognized in SQL statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am getting an error saying the equal sign is not recognized. I always test my code in Access to make sure it will work. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Code:

```
SELECT SUM(
                       IIf(TransactionType = 'Cash', 
                       TotalPrice, 0)
           ) AS TotalCash, 
       SUM(
                       IIf(TransactionType = 'Credit', 
                       TotalPrice, 0)
           ) AS TotalCredit,
       SUM(
                       IIf(TransactionType = 'Check', 
                       TotalPrice, 0)
           ) AS TotalCheck,
       SUM(
                       IIf(TransactionType = 'Multiple', 
                       IIf(MultiCash = 0, 
                        0, MultiCash), 0)
           ) AS MultipleCash,
       SUM(
                       IIf(TransactionType = 'Multiple', 
                       IIf(MultiCredit= 0, 
                        0, MultiCredit), 0)
           ) AS MultipleCredit,
       SUM(
                       IIf(TransactionType = 'Multiple', 
                       IIf(MultiCheck = 0, 
                        0, MultiCheck), 0)
           ) AS MultipleCheck

FROM  RECEIPT 

WHERE ReceiptDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Error:

```
Generated SELECT statement.
   Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recongized.
   Unable to parse query text.
```

EDIT:

Let me tell you what I want to do instead of just posting code. It may be another easy solution to this problem. So I want to pull a report from the report viewer in vb.net to tell me the tender that was used between specific dates.

Ex.

```
1/20/2013
Transaction Type                 Amount
Cash                             $100.00
Check                            $300.00
Credit                           $1,000.00
MultiCash                        $1,500.00
MultiCheck                       $1,500.00
MultiCredit                      $1,500.00
```

Something like that in the report viewer. The user will be able to chose specific dates.
My Access database table to pull information from is as shown below.

```
  RECEIPT
-----------
ReceiptNumber (PK)
ReceiptDate
TotalPrice
TransactionType
MultiCash
MultiCheck
MultiCredit
TotalTax
```

Any other ways of doing this, maybe?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Where are you running this code from and getting the error?  You had `vb.net` as a tag; is this a `TableAdapter`, or a query you are attempting to run from `vb.net` code?

Comment: are you running this code in Access or another database?

Comment: I am running in a TableAdapter, Yes in vb.net. The database is an Access database.

Comment: I think you may need to post a little of the code around that.

Comment: Are you trying to use the option `"Create methods to send updates directly to the database"` in the TableAdapter wizard?  That's not going to work because you currently don't have an updateable query.  You'll need to write the rest of the CRUD statements yourself, or get the complicated `IIF` logic out of your `SELECT` statement and into the application display logic - the TableAdapter is designed for simple `SELECT * FROM Table` or `SELECT F1, F2, F3, ... FROM Table` types of queries.

Comment: There is none. That is it.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to use the wizard this one "Select which returns rows" in an already updateable table.

Comment: Can you post a series of screenshots as you progress through each step of the wizard, what you're typing, what options you're selecting, and finally the error message as it's displayed on the screen?  I think you're using an option that is not compatible with the type of query you have.  Also, you may find it easier to skip the `TableAdapter` approach altogether and just use an `OdbcConnection` and `OdbcCommand` to retrieve the data.

Comment: A `GROUP BY` statement would make that a much easier to read query.

Comment: @Dan-o  GROUP BY is unnecessary when only one field (column) is returned. The sql is a perfectly valid MS Access select query. However, it is not an updatable query.

Comment: @Remou: I was suggesting the query be rotated to return multiple rows, instead of a cross-tab.  It was a comment about the query structure, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clauses like:

```
IIf(MultiCash = 0, 0, MultiCash)
```

Do absolutely nothing. You're saying "if multicash is 0, use 0, otherwise use the value..."

It looks like an overly complex way of doing it. Try this, it'll give you data in a slightly different format, but I suspect it'll be close to what you're after

```
SELECT TransactionType, 
       SUM(TotalPrice)  AS SumTotalPrice,
       SUM(MultiCash )  AS MultipleCash,
       SUM(MultiCredit) AS MultipleCredit,
       SUM(MultiCheck ) AS MultipleCheck
FROM  Receipt 
WHERE ReceiptDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY TransactionType
```

It also has the upside that the query will naturally handle new payment types introduced at a later date.